# Error when adding torrents to deluge with python: User does not exists

Tags: bash, python, deluge, raspberrypi

I am trying to write a python script to download my tv shows automatically as soon as they become available. I got the basics done. But i cant get to add torrent to deluge via deluge-console.

The line that does the adding operation is:

```
os.system("deluge-console add -p /media/hdd/Diziler/"+apiInput["title"].replace(" ", "")+" "+i["torrents"]["480p"]["url"])
```

it simply creates a string in this format "deluge-console add -p path magnet" and pushes it to the system. But i get a BadLoginError: User name does not exists.

I dont do any system calls before hand and this is a clean deluge install. I can add torrents through web ui.

Thanks all in advance.

Edit: Full error

```
[ERROR   ] 13:58:32 client:391 RPCError Message Received!
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RPCRequest: daemon.login(, )
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deluge/core/rpcserver.py", line 260, in dispatch
ret = component.get("AuthManager").authorize(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deluge/core/authmanager.py", line 87, in         authorize
raise BadLoginError("Username does not exist")
BadLoginError: Username does not exist
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to connect to localhost:58846 with reason: Username does not exist
```

Comment: What version of Deluge?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure precisely the issue here but it is likely that you will need to setup a user as per [Thinclient guide](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/ThinClient#AddUsertotheauthenticationfile) and then use the console `connect` command:

`deluge-console "connect 127.0.0.1:58846 user pass; add -p ..."`